# delete an object form nested array in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

here is my array i want to remove an object "sec b" in second class from classes array,i tried in many ways can anyone help me out

```
[
    {
        "classes": [
            {
                "class_name": "fist class",
                "sections": [
                    {
                        "section_name": "section a"
                    },{
                        "section_name": "section b"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "class_name": "second class",
                "sections": [
                    {
                        "section_name": "sect a"
                    },
                    {
                        "section_name": "sec b"
                    },
                    {
                        "section_name": "sec c"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "_id": "id",
        "name": "testing",
       
    }
]
```

I have treid like this

```
db.update({ _id: req.params.id},{$pull:{"classes.$.sections":{section_name:'sec b'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.update({
  _id: req.params.id,
  "classes.class_name": "second class"
},
{
  $pull: {
    sections: {
      "section_name": "sect a"
    }
  }
})


//also check your req.params.id is ObjectId not string
```

Comment: what if the "section a" was present in both "first class" and "second class" , I want to remove in "second class" only

Comment: I have tried in this way then it was working

div.update({ _id: req.params.id, "classes.class_name": req.body.class_name },
    { $pull: { "classes.$.sections": { "section_name": req.body.section_name } } })

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.